# Python NumPy concatenate 2 triangular arrays above/below diagonal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, diagonal

I am trying to combine 2 triangular NumPy arrays into a new array in Python. Each triangular array is half filled with values, with zeros on the diagonal. I need to merge these 2 arrays into one new combined array with zeros on the diagonal.

Here is the array `X`

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(4,4)

[[ 0.06681579  0.25793063  0.86489791  0.78399056]
 [ 0.7335036   0.99703778  0.40017913  0.07912444]
 [ 0.43533884  0.51517525  0.28110527  0.10793738]
 [ 0.19212844  0.704657    0.94657795  0.89042305]]
```

I then extract the [lower](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html)
and a modified version of the [upper](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) diagonal values from the array:

```
u = np.triu(X+1,k=1)
l = np.tril(X,k=-1)
print u
[[ 0.          1.25793063  1.86489791  1.78399056]
 [ 0.          0.          1.40017913  1.07912444]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          1.10793738]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]

print l
[[ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.7335036   0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.43533884  0.51517525  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.19212844  0.704657    0.94657795  0.        ]]
```

Now, I need to combine these 2 arrays `u` and `l` together such that:

1. the upper triangle (not including diagonal) is filled with `u`
2. the lower triangle (not including diagonal) is filled with `l`
3. the diagonal is still filled with zeros

Here is what I am looking for:

```
[[ 0.          1.25793063  1.86489791  1.78399056]
 [ 0.7335036   0.          1.40017913  1.07912444]
 [ 0.43533884  0.51517525  0.          1.10793738]
 [ 0.19212844  0.704657    0.94657795  0.        ]]
```

Is there a way to concatenate these 2 NumPy arrays to get this output?

Comment: ul = np.where(u==0,l,u) perhaps

Comment: Ok, I marked the answer below as accepted. However, this method is really concise and also works. I tried `u[u == 0] = l` but that didn't work. Great answer. Thanks @NaN.

Comment: It is useful... a = np.zeros((4,4),dtype=int) ... b = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4) ... u = np.triu(a+1,k=1)  ... try ... np.where(u==0, b, a) ... or ... np.where(u==0, a+5, b) ... enables shortcuts to several array construction alternatives. Plus you can use ... ur = np.rot90(u) ... if the orientation of triu or trial doesn't suit

Comment: Ok, from reading the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), I am not sure I understand the logic in `ul = np.where(u==0,l,u)`. Could you perhaps explain how it is possible to use both `l` and `u` simultaneously to replace `u = 0` values?

Comment: you can play with the k factor in either ie l = np.tril(x,k=1) and the ul will change on the diagonal.  alternately, or in conjunction with that, you can change the 'where' conditional statement from ==  what you get depends on those... my second comment was on using the tri variants with conditional statements and reorientation of existing or output structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
u+l
```

That should suffice for most cases. If you need to be careful about preserving signed zeros, you can do something more cumbersome:

```
result = u.copy()
l_indices = numpy.tril_indices_from(l)
result[l_indices] = l[l_indices]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to take values directly, without using indices. That didn't work. This works great!

Comment: What if the values are strings?